# What do rows 3 and 4 of the pdetool MATLAB matrix e represent?

Tags: matlab, pde

I'm trying to figure out what rows 3 and 4 of the `e` matrix in the MATLAB `pdetool` represent.
According to the [documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/mesh-data-pet-triples.html):

- `e(3,k)` is the parameter value at the first point of edge `k`. The
  parameter value is related to the arc length along the geometric
  edge.
- `e(4,k)` is the parameter value at the second point of edge `k`.

Even with the definition, I can't understand it.

Comment: Is it not the value of the parameter that you are trying to solve? say e.g. you are using the mesh for temperature on a plate. is `e(3:4,:)` the values of the temperature at those points? Its the first thing that comes to mind, but I have not used it.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thanks for your suggestion but it can't be that as I define my mesh (I find the p,t and e matrices) only from the geometry and before I do the computations by the finite element method.